# Setting up Ruff (Python Linter)

Tags: python, pycodestyle, ruff

As far as I understood `ruff` implements `pycodestyle` rules by default. However, when I run my code through pycodestyle I get:

```
test.py:5:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1
test.py:8:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1
test.py:13:9: E129 visually indented line with same indent as next logical line
test.py:22:1: E305 expected 2 blank lines after class or function definition, found 1
test.py:32:5: E265 block comment should start with '# '
test.py:34:5: E265 block comment should start with '# '
test.py:43:14: W292 no newline at end of file
```

While `ruff` gives me all good.

Anyone can tell me why that is the case?

Answer (score 2):

As for 09.09.23, [merge request](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/pull/4694) for errors **E301-6** is not approved yet. Same thing for other errors by `pycodestyle`.

You can check errors that are handled by ruff [here](https://beta.ruff.rs/docs/rules/).

Answer (score 2):

It is finally [merged](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/pull/9266). You just have to enable the [preview flag](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/preview/)

Just add this to your .toml file

```py
[tool.ruff.lint]
preview = true
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says in [documentation](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/rules/):

> By default, Ruff enables Flake8's F rules, along with a subset of the E rules

To capture all pydocstyle rules (E, W), you should configure ruff in `pyproject.toml` as follows:

```
[tool.ruff.lint]
extend-select = ["W", "E"]
preview = true
```